# Am not able to install other debian packages after installing google chrome. what could be the issue?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, google-chrome

```
$ sudo apt-get install cryptkeeper
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

The lists shouldn't contain the file:

```
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en
```

The only files that it should contain are:

```
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg
```

Please do this and report back if there are still any errors:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cryptkeeper
```